# Custom mouse cursor not appearing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I used this CSS snippet to show a custom cursor in my site. But the problem is it doesn't appear in Chrome but it does on Firefox.

I don't know how to resolve this issue.

```
cursor: url('https://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
```

Comment: It should work. inspect the element and make sure if the cursor rule is not overwritten by another rule?

Comment: I've tried it. No overridden rule.

Comment: Another possibility is that the image is being loaded from cache or previous version. open the Chrome Developer Tools, go to network tab, Check the "Disbale Cache" and refresh the page to make sure that the image is a fresh version.

Comment: i tried your code its working in chrome

Comment: In console it says `finger.png:1 GET https://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: It can be a CORS issue...

Comment: Can you please explain it?